# Custom API specify multidimensional parameter

Tags: api, custom, array

I already created custom api where I am able to pass array item (for example

```
$data = array('date'=>'2013-12-22','operation'=>'import','successful'=>'1', 'requeue'=>'0');)
```

but I would like to be able to pass multi dimensional array. Something like this:

```
$data = array(
    0 => array('date'=>'2013-12-22','operation'=>'import','successful'=>'1', 'requeue'=>'0'),
    1 => array('date'=>'2013-12-28','operation'=>'export','successful'=>'0', 'requeue'=>'1')
);
```

If I pass such an array I am getting only first record. How I should change my api getting the results I want?

this is how I am calling my api:

```
<?php
  $host = "127.0.0.1/magento/index.php";
  $client = new SoapClient("http://".$host. "/api/soap/?wsdl");
  $apiuser= "test";
  $apikey = "123";
  $action = "sync.items";
  $data = array(
            0 => array('date'=>'2013-12-22','operation'=>'import','successful'=>'1', 'requeue'=>'0'),
            1 => array('date'=>'2013-12-28','operation'=>'export','successful'=>'0', 'requeue'=>'1')
);

try { 
  $sessionId= $client->login($apiuser, $apikey);
  $result = array();

  $result= $client->call($sessionId, $action, $data);
  var_dump($result);

}
catch (Exception $e){
  echo var_dump($e);
  throw $e;
}
```

wsdl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
<types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
        <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        <complexType name="syncreportsSyncItemsEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="date" type="xsd:date" minOccurs="1" />
                <element name="operation" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
                <element name="successful" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" />
                <element name="requeue" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" />
            </all>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="syncreportsSyncItemsEntityArray">
            <complexContent>
                <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                    <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:syncreportsSyncListEntity[]" />
                </restriction>
            </complexContent>
        </complexType>

        <complexType name="syncreportsSyncCreateEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="date" type="xsd:date" minOccurs="1" />
                <element name="operation" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
                <element name="successful" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" />
                <element name="requeue" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" />
            </all>
        </complexType>

    </schema>
</types>
<message name="syncreportsSyncItemsRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="data" type="typens:syncreportsSyncItemsEntity" />
</message>
<message name="syncreportsSyncItemsResponse">
    <part name="result" type="typens:syncreportsSyncItemsEntityArray" />
</message>
<message name="syncreportsSyncCreateRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="data" type="xsd:syncreportsSyncCreateEntity" />
</message>
<message name="syncreportsSyncCreateResponse">
    <part name="result" type="typens:syncreportsSyncCreateEntityArray" />
</message>
<portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <operation name="syncreportsSyncItems">
        <documentation>Retrieve sync info</documentation>
        <input message="typens:syncreportsSyncItemsRequest" />
        <output message="typens:syncreportsSyncItemsResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="syncreportsSyncCreate">
        <documentation>Retrieve sync info</documentation>
        <input message="typens:syncreportsSyncCreateRequest" />
        <output message="typens:syncreportsSyncCreateResponse" />
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="syncreportsSyncItems">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
        <input>
            <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </output>
    </operation>

    <operation name="syncreportsSyncCreate">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
        <input>
            <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
    <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
        <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

wsi.xml

```
        <xsd:complexType name="syncreportsSyncCreateEntity">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:date" />
                <xsd:element name="operation" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="successful" type="xsd:int" />
                <xsd:element name="requeue" type="xsd:int" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>


        <xsd:element name="syncreportsSyncCreateRequestParam">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="data" type="typens:portfolioProjectAddEntity" />
                </xsd:sequence>
             </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="syncreportsSyncCreateResponseParam">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="typens:portfolioProjectInfoEntityArray" />
                </xsd:sequence>
             </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>


        <xsd:element name="syncreportsSyncItemsRequestParam">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="data" type="typens:portfolioProjectAddEntity" />
                </xsd:sequence>
             </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="syncreportsSyncItemsResponseParam">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="typens:portfolioProjectInfoEntityArray" />
                </xsd:sequence>
             </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>


<wsdl:message name="syncreportsSyncItemsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:syncreportsSyncItemsRequestParam" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="syncreportsSyncItemsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:syncreportsSyncItemsResponseParam" />
</wsdl:message>


<wsdl:message name="syncreportsSyncCreateRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:syncreportsSyncCreateRequestParam" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="syncreportsSyncItemsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:syncreportsSyncCreateResponseParam" />
</wsdl:message>


<wsdl:portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="syncreportsSyncItems">
        <wsdl:documentation>Retrieve project info</wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="typens:syncreportsSyncItemsRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="typens:syncreportsSyncItemsResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>


<wsdl:portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="syncreportsSyncCreate">
        <wsdl:documentation>Retrieve project info</wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="typens:syncreportsSyncCreateRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="typens:syncreportsSyncCreateResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>



<wsdl:binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="syncreportsSyncItems">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="syncreportsSyncCreate">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
    <wsdl:port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
        <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `multiCall` method instead of `call`. It should allow you to call multiple methods at once.

```
$result = $client->multiCall($session, array(
     array('somestuff.method'),
     array('somestuff.method', 'arg1'),
     array('somestuff.method', array('arg1', 'arg2'))
));
```

In your case it can go something like this:

```
$action = "sync.items";
$data = array(
        0 => array('date'=>'2013-12-22','operation'=>'import','successful'=>'1', 'requeue'=>'0'),
        1 => array('date'=>'2013-12-28','operation'=>'export','successful'=>'0', 'requeue'=>'1'); 

$params = array(); 
foreach ($data as $item){
    $params[] = array($action, $item);
}

$result = $client->multiCall($session, $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `arguments` node inside `arguments` node. So you won't need to use `multiCall` anymore. See line #292 `magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php`  -- file reference is form magento ver. 1.9.3.9.

```
<methods>
   <items translate="title" module="foo_module">
      <title>Update item</title>
      <method>items</method>
      <arguments>array</arguments>
      <acl>foo_module/api/items</acl>
   </items>
</methods>
```